# Transfer for loop to recursion, Java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to transfer for loop to recrusion function..

This is my fucntion:

```
public void AddEnemyToScreen(int enemy_count)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<enemy_count;i++)
    {
        AddEnemey(new Enemy(r.nextInt(640), -10, textures,this,game));
    }
}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
public void AddEnemyToScreen(int enemy_count)
{
    if ( enemy_count == 1)
        AddEnemey(new Enemy(r.nextInt(640), -10, textures,this,game));
    else
    {
        AddEnemyToScreen(--enemy_count);
    }

}
```

but in some reason it dosent works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition in the recursive function is to add an enemy only when enemy_count is equal to 1, meaning you will only add one enemy.

```
public void AddEnemyToScreen(int enemy_count)
{

    // As long as enemy count is positive, keep adding enemies.
    if ( enemy_count > 0) {
             // Add new enemy to screen
            AddEnemey(new Enemy(r.nextInt(640), -10, textures,this,game));
            AddEnemyToScreen(enemy_count-1); // Add one more            
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it does, it will return when enemy_count is equal to 0, since then it wont call the recursive function :)

Comment: I tried this right now..even if I send to the function count of 0 the thread addes new enemies all the time

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Bug fixed.